# Ubuntu 14.4 Firefox crashes

Tags: firefox, crash

Last week as usual I updated using software updater, ever since then Firefox has been crashing every few minutes. I have uninstalled and reinstalled it and still get the same issue.

```
error Add-ons: ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.0,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:39.0,langpack-en-ZA%40firefox.mozilla.org:39.0,langpack-en-GB%40firefox.mozilla.org:39.0
AsyncPluginInit: 0
BuildID: 20150629114848
CrashTime: 1437249180
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1437248944
Notes: OpenGL: nouveau -- Gallium 0.4 on NV84 -- 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 -- texture_from_pixmap

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox

ReleaseChannel: release
StartupTime: 1437248944
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
URL: https://www.facebook.com/groups/169400596589179/388879494641287/?notif_t=group_activity
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 39.0
useragent_locale: chrome://global/locale/intl.properties
```

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.

Can't figure out what's causing it to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess the cause of the crash is a addon:

```
error Add-ons: ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.0,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:39.0,langpack-en-ZA%40firefox.mozilla.org:39.0,langpack-en-GB%40firefox.mozilla.org:39.0
```

Usually when Firefox updates these need to be upgraded, and this is usually done automatically, but in this case it won't. To try and fix it:

- [Start Firefox in Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) - you can probably also do this using the command
   `firefox -safe-mode` in terminal, and then selecting Safe Mode. Then try to uninstall or disable the problematic addons in the Extensions/Languages sections of the Addon Manager. Close Firefox and open it again to see if it worked.
- [Make a new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) (use `firefox -P`), or [reset firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) (use `firefox -safe-mode` again, but select Refresh). This is issue probably is just with the one addon so I would recommend trying normal Safe Mode and trying to disable it first.

Comment: thank you, it now stops crashing, it seems that there was two different issues of flash so it had the conflict issue i guess :) i will save this incase i get same issue again!